# Creating an RVIZ plugin to add semantic information to a map

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, plugin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I repeat [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/40468/creating-an-rviz-plugin-for-a-new-display-type/) posted 2 years ago, except that we need a plugin for a different purpose. We plan to create a graphical editor to add semantic information to 2D/3D maps, and a RViz plugin could be the ideal solution. Rqt plugins look great for simple interfaces, but we need the fully-fledged 3D interface that RViz provides. So it's still not recommended to make a RViz plugins?

I already started a   plugin, reusing rqt_nav_view to load a 2D map, but I'm afraid that make it fully 3D will be a lot of development effort, and I don't have enough time.

Thanks for any input!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191081/creating-an-rviz-plugin-to-add-semantic-information-to-a-map/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2014-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The RViz plugin API is stable now, and it's possible to write display plugins for specialized data types. I maintain a number of custom rviz plugins as part of my day job.

The rviz wiki page has tutorials for writing new [display types](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Plugins%3A%20New%20Display%20Type), [panels](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Plugins%3A%20New%20Dockable%20Panel) and [tools](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Plugins%3A%20New%20Tool%20Type).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-08-23**:
Excellent! Thanks for the information.